# WPF Data Binding of Width Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the Width property of a Canvas to the Width property of a Shape instance. So the Shape Width should be updated when the Canvas Width gets a new value

I want to do that in code, without XAML, because I create these elements on runtime.

I tried this, but it didnt work (the code is inside of my Canvas):

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;
binding.Source = this;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Width");
shape.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, binding);
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

ksman

Comment: While running, could you check the output window for databinding failures?

Answer (score 2):

`OneTime` looks wrong. I think you want to use `OneWay` or `TwoWay`. Check [the BindingModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx)

**Edit**

Since `OneWay` and `ActualWidth` didn't fix your problem, I should recommend you use a tool for debugging bindings. I use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) because it is free, but there are others. Debugging WPF without a tool like this can be painful.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to bind to `ActualWidth` and not `Width`.

`Width` is an *input* into the layout process -- it's something you may (but don't have to) specify.

`ActualWidth` is an *output* of the layout process -- it's the actual width that you see on the screen. This is partly determined by `Width`, if present, but other factors go into it too (especially if you didn't explicitly set `Width` in your XAML).

Comment: I changed the PropertyPath to "ActualWidth" and the Mode to "OneWay". But it still doesn't work :-(